# Too many arguments error from method with only one required argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

When I'm trying to give the music loader the selected music file an error occurs:

The code:

```
import essentia
import essentia.standard
import os


file = os.listdir()
i = 0

number = len(file)
print("Number:", number)

while i<number:
    if file[i].endswith(".mp3"):
        print(file[i])

        filename = file[i]

        loader = essentia.standard.MonoLoader(file[i]) #<--ERROR 

        audio = loader()

        #...
```

The error:

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I searched and found that not only the filename is passed, but the "self-argument(list-object named file)" as well. Did I get this right? And now the question: How can I pass the elements of this list without the self argument?

Comment: Solved:import essentia
import essentia.standard
from glob import glob

for filename in glob('*.mp3'):
    print(filename)
    loader = essentia.standard.MonoLoader(filename=filename)

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the [essentia docs for the MonoLoader method](https://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_MonoLoader.html), it looks like it takes multiple parameters and `filename` is not the first parameter (all other parameters are optional except the filename). So you will need to specify that you are passing the `filename` parameter. For example:

```
loader = essentia.standard.MonoLoader(filename=file[i])
```

Also, if your sample code is not really indicative of where your mp3 files are located, then be sure to pass the full file path to `MonoLoader` and not just the filename.

Finally, I assume you are just showing a part of your `while` loop in your question and that you are in fact incrementing `i` somewhere so that it does not run forever.